# Create array of arrays by assigning keys while creating sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I could write it out like this.

```
 $key = "sid";
 $values = array(1,2,3);
 $desired_array = array();

 foreach($values as $value){
     $desired_array[] = array($key => $value);
 }

 print_r($desired_array);
```

The output would look like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sid] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sid] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sid] => 3
        )     
)
```

I was hoping there was a fancy php array function I didn't know about that could create that for me so keep my code terser.

Here's the completed solution, maybe it's not much shorter but I'm always happy when I get to use array_map.

```
 $key = "sid";
 $values = array(1,2,3);
 $desired_array = array_map(function($value) use($key){
    return array($key=>$value);
 },$values);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative solution using `array_map` function:

```
$desired_array = array_map(function($v) use($key){ return [$key => $v]; }, $values);
```

Comment: The use($key) is exactly what I needed to make array_map work the way I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

It would work something like this:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$desired = array_map(function ($item) {return ['sid' => $item];}, $array);
```

I believe this [link](https://3v4l.org/fsm8t) should work for a demonstration as well.

Comment: Thanks, but it was the use() that I was missing when I initially tried array_map. It was in RomanPerekhrest's answer.

Comment: Yep, if you want a variable key his is the better answer.